# DOM Navigation - unexpected value

Tags: javascript, dom

Please see my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="H1">H1 text H1 text H1 text</h1>

<p id="P2">P2 P2 P2</p>

<script>
var Text = document.getElementById("H1").childNodes[-5].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("P2").innerHTML = Text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How is it that when my page is loaded I see in paragraph P2 the same text?

Why don't I see "undefined" or "null" written in it?

Comment: Because the second line never executes. Look at your console. You should see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined`. Because you get an error on the line that assigns `Text` you never execute the second line.

Comment: Ok. But if I write a wrong index (like 333 or -10), why don't I see in the page the word "undefined" or "null"? Why the script is ignoring me?

Comment: Because your script is broken. What do you expect it to do when it encounters an error? Carry on regardless? That's not how it works. Execution will stop at the first error. Your script isn't ignoring you, you are ignoring it when it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You H1 element only has one child node, a text node.  If you change your index to 0 like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="H1">H1 text H1 text H1 text</h1>

<p id="P2">P2 P2 P2</p>

<script>
var Text = document.getElementById("H1").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("P2").innerHTML = Text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you'll see that it now executes, although it is not clear to me what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Because the second line never executes. Look at your console. You should see (on Chrome at least, other browser may have slightly different verbage) `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined`.

Your script will **STOP** execution at the first error it encounters. That's just the way it works:

```
var Text = document.getElementById("H1").childNodes[-5].nodeValue;  // <-- execution 
                                                                    // stops here
document.getElementById("P2").innerHTML = Text;       // <!-- this line never executes
```

What is happening is that:

```
document.getElementById("H1").childNodes[-5]
```

will return `undefined` (I suspect you know this, hence your question). You then try to access the property `.nodeValue` on `undefined`. This throws an error just as surely as if you'd directly typed:

```
undefined.nodeValue
```

Into your console (go ahead and try it). If it ignored the error and continued trying to execute the result would be unexpected and could lead to further (and more serious) errors later in the script.

If your idea was to be able to check if a node exists, then you could do something like:

```js
var Text = undefined; 
if (document.getElementById("H1").childNodes[-5]) {
  // undefined is falsy - so this next line won't execute and we'll get no errors
  Text = document.getElementById("H1").childNodes[-5].nodeValue;
}
// now .innerHTML will get "undefined"
document.getElementById("P2").innerHTML = Text;
```

```html
<h1 id="H1">H1 text H1 text H1 text</h1>

<p id="P2">P2 P2 P2</p>
```